# Framework not working in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ddmathparser

I am using DDMathParser in my project. I have set the deployment target to iOS 8.0 of my project. My project is running fine on iOS 9 emulator but not my iPhone which is running iOS 8.4. The [documentation](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki) of library shows that it is supported on iOS 8.0+. But when I run it on my iPhone it just shows the initial launch screen and crashes.

Edit 1: after clean build it is still not working following message is displayed

dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
->  0x1200e5088 <+0>: brk    #0x3

Comment: Try to clean the build and run it again. I am faceing same issue now and then.

Comment: Show the exception message and full stack trace